# Problems with citations

Tags: bibtex, citing, cite-package, multiple-citations

I have LaTex document with this preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Referring to the literature I get
[image: The links look like]

```
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

How do I get the alternation of literature through a dash, like this? [1-9]
For references I use the command \cite

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Wild guess, but try `\documentclass[12pt,1p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}` (_i.e.,_ add the `sort&compress` option).

Comment: Why did you tag the `cite-package`? The `elsarticle` document class loads the `natbib` package automatically, and the `natbib` and `cite` packages are mutually incompatible with each other.